# Scope handling in OAuth2 protocol

Tags: oauth

I have a general question regarding how scopes in the OAuth2 protocol
are handled. For easy argumentation lets start with a concrete example:

Lets say I have an OAuth server `A` which I want to use in order to protect two
RESTful APIs `R1` and `R2`. These two services have special scopes that they use to grant a user access to some protected resources. So lets say `R1` needs the scope `S1` and `R2` needs the scope `S2` in order to access some restricted resources.

Lets further say that the OAuth server A makes also use of the scopes `email` and `profile`, they are needed to access the user data that the OAuth server itself manages.

Now here is what I'm having trouble to understand. As far as I can see the OAuth server `A` normally only knows how to handle the scopes that he itself uses (in this case `email` and `profile`). But what about the scopes that are required in order to access the restricted functionality on the two APIs (`R1` needs `S1` and `R2` needs `S2`)?

Do I have to register these scopes manually with the OAuth server (so that it knows that they exist and can grant them should that be needed)?
That again would mean that I need to register all scopes of all the APIs that I want to protect/use using the OAuth server.

Are these assumptions correct? If I get something wrong here perhaps someone can help me by explaining how the entire scope handling is normally implemented. I tried to google `oauth2` and `scopes` but there seems to be no good explanation of how exactly scopes are handled in the protocol.